# Looking for a .NET ObjectReflector that will help me simplify reflecting an object

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I've got a class that receives an object from other unknown modules and so I have to do reflection on the object to get its data, call its methods, etc.

To simplify the code to reflect on the object, I'm building this class:

```
using System;

namespace ApplicationCore.Helpers
{
    class ObjectReflector
    {
        public object TheObject { get; set; }
        public Type TheType { get; set; }

        public ObjectReflector(object theObject)
        {
            TheObject = theObject;
            TheType = theObject.GetType();
        }

        public string GetObjectShortName()
        {
            return TheObject.GetType().Name;
        }

        public string GetObjectLongName()
        {
            return TheObject.GetType().ToString();
        }

        public T GetPropertyValue<T>(string propertyName)
        {
            return (T)TheType.GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(TheObject, null);
        }

        public T GetMethodValue<T>(string methodName, object[] parameters)
        {
            return (T)TheType.GetMethod(methodName).Invoke(TheObject, parameters);
        }

    }
}
```

So that I have nice, clean code that looks like this:

```
namespace ApplicationCore.Presenters
{
    public class SmartFormPresenter
    {
        public UserControl View { get; set; }

        public string ShortName { get; set; }
        public string LongName { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public int AgePlusTwo { get; set; }

        public SmartFormPresenter(object o)
        {
            SmartFormView smartFormView = new SmartFormView();
            View = smartFormView;
            smartFormView.DataContext = this;

            ObjectReflector or = new ObjectReflector(o);
            ShortName = or.GetObjectShortName();
            LongName = or.GetObjectLongName();
            FirstName = or.GetPropertyValue<string>("FirstName");
            Age = or.GetPropertyValue<int>("Age");
            AgePlusTwo = or.GetMethodValue<int>("GetAgeInTwoYears", null);
        }
    }
}
```

But now I need to make methods e.g. to read out not an **int** but a **`List<Contract>`** so that I'm going to have to get a `List<object>` and then reflect on the "object" etc.

So I'm thinking that this has been done before. **Is there any kind of tool or class in .NET called ObjectReflector that will help me simplify the reflection of an object as I'm doing above?**

Comment: I wouldn't use property and method names directly. Instead use linq expression trees to avoid them. This makes refactoring safer.

Comment: I've got method and property names in an XML file as strings that I need to call on my unknown object. How would that work in this case with ling expression trees?

Comment: if i understood correctly you want to extract a Collection from your unknown object and then in turn reflect on the objects of the collection?

Comment: yes, simple types (int, string) I can get with my GetPropertyValue() method, but now I need to get types that are also unknown (defined in other modules), e.g. my xml file says that I need to call a method on every element in the List<Contract> property.

Comment: thats tricky. You certainly can check if the property type implements ICollection, then get the first element and reflect on that. Problems will arise when inheritance is used.
I can imagine that performance is a concern also. You might want to check out my project "ModelShredder" on Googlecode which shows how to efficiently implement property access via a dynamic method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldnt post code in my comment. This can get you started:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in oProps)
           {
                Type colType = pi.PropertyType;

                if ((colType.IsGenericType) && (colType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()      
                ==typeof(Nullable<>)))
                 {
                     colType = colType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                 }
```